# Disabling certain tests in Mesos

Tags: mesos

How do I disable certain specific tests in mesos?
Say for example, I wish to disable `TestCategory.SpecificTest` from running when I execute `make check`. How do I do that? Where do I make those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways.

#### Specify `GTEST_FILTER` to `make check`.

```
make check GTEST_FILTER=-TestCategory.SpecificTest
```

#### Mark a test as `DISABLED`.

```
TEST(TestCategory, DISABLED_SpecificTest) { ... }
```

#### References

- [Running a Subset of the Tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests).
- [Temporarily Disabling Tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Temporarily_Disabling_Tests)